# Decrease load time of an Polymer 1.X app

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, vulcanize

I have a Polymer application, and I would like to find the easiest possible path to decrease load times.

The app is online (although it's TOTALLY unfinished): http://www.entertainers.biz/

At the moment, load times are *geological*.

I tried `polymer build`, but only got marginal improvements. The problem is that fetching the app is 219 request (two hundred and nine-teen!).

Ideally, I would turn the two main files (my-main.html and my-app.html) into something static. I experimented with vulcanize, and when I tried to vulcanize one or the other, the whole thing basically stopped working.

Another approach would be to create a file that includes *everything* needed by my-app and my-main in terms of imports (and just those), and then include the vulcanised version of those, so that *those* become one call (of around 1Mb).

Am I missing something totally obvious?

Comment: You said you used `polymer build` but it looks like your have deployed the unbundled version rather than the bundled version which will cut down on the number of requests you are making. What you could also do is look at lazy loading your components as and when they are needed. This will dramatically increase the initial render.

Comment: Use the `polymer-cli` to generate the Shop app and have a look at how the elements are lazy loaded in this.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem I was having were caused by https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/444